# how to select all input elements in a different TD

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dynamic

I have an `<table>` created dinamically at runtime. This table has three columns:

1. in the first `TD` there is always a `<input type="checkbox">` element
2. the second `TD` is not important
3. in the third `TD` there is always an HTML input element. This can be an `<input>`, `<select>`

I need to enable/disable the input elements that are in the third `TD` when I click on the checkbox that is on the first `TD`

I know how to bind an event handler on the checkbox but I dont know how to select "*all the `<input>` and `<select>` elements that will be inside the same row but in the third `TD`*"

This is a sample markup that I have

```
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="chkSelectField" type="checkbox" name="chkSelectField" 
             onclick="disableControl('chkSelectField');" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input name="control1" type="text" id="control1" />
        <input name="control2" type="text" id="control2" />
        <select name="control3" type="text" id="control3">...</select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
$('td input:checkbox').click(function() {         
    var t = $(this);
    var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) :input');
    if (t.is(':checked')) {
        inputs.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        inputs.removeAttr('disabled');         
    }
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/R5Lck/1/

Answer (score 2):

Inside your click handler:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) :input')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the event handler for the checkbox, put this:

```
$(this).parent().next().next().find('input,select')
```